# Slow initial loading of Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd under load

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webresource.axd

We're using the Telerik.RadScriptManager to dynamicly register resources depending on the controls on the page. These get combined and served as a single .axd for all .js files. This works fine as long there is no "heavy" load on the page. Under load the inital loading of the Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd takes up to 10s, reloading the page afterwards however is instant (~10ms). The file is around 200kb in size and in FireBug i see the browser "waiting" for the request. This happens per user/browser, it isn't cached globally on the server. The server CPUs aren't stressed at all (<10%), so where is the bottleneck? What takes so long? Any hints where i could investigate this further?

Thx

UPDATE: 
Narrowed it down to the RadScriptManager EnableScriptCombine feature. Disabling this and there is no performance impact anymore. But then I have 20 more requests...
Anyone an idea how to speed this up? Another idea would be to generate/combine the script with the RadScriptManager and then saving it next to the page as it won't change.

Comment: I think the reloading of the page measured in MS time is related to the caching of the JS file...

Comment: @Brian, you're right. But caching on the client isn't really an option as it is slow for every different page.

Comment: I assume you have the handler defined in both system.web and system.webServer in your config?

Comment: yep, everything is registered correct. we just disabled the ScriptCombine feature and the page is up and running. the +20 requests are ugly, but atm there is no time for fixing this...